# Ordenar a tabela datatable pela data dos registros

Tags: codeigniter, jquery-datatables, order-by

Tenho um código, que ao iniciar, ele cria uma tabela usando ***dataTable***. Os dados dessa tabela vem do meu banco MySQL. Não sei ao certo como está a ordenação dos meus registros, se eu não me engano está vindo pelo Id, mas preciso que venha ordenado pela Data de cada registro.

No MySQL e no model do codeigniter (que eu estou usando) sei como fazer, porém quando não está sendo usado o ***dataTable***. Já com ele, não sei como faço.
Meu código como falei antes está em **CodeIgniter**.

A parte que faz essa tabela fica assim:

```
var oTable = $('#tabletools').dataTable({
        "sProcessing": '<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_process"); ?>',
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bAutoWidth": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo base_url() . $caminho; ?>",
        "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
            $("td:nth-child(1)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("th:nth-child(1)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("td:nth-child(4)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("th:nth-child(4)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("td:nth-child(5)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("th:nth-child(5)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("td:nth-child(6)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("th:nth-child(6)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("td:nth-child(7)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("th:nth-child(7)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip();
        },
        "oLanguage": {
            "sProcessing": "<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_process"); ?>",
            "sZeroRecords": "<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_records"); ?>",
            "sInfo": "<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_info"); ?>",
            "sInfoEmpty": "<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_empty"); ?>",
            "sInfoFiltered": "<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_filter"); ?>",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sUrl": "",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst": "<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_first"); ?>",
                "sPrevious": "<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_previous"); ?>",
                "sNext": "<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_next"); ?>",
                "sLast": "<?= $this->lang->line("datatable_last"); ?>"
            }
        },
        "fnInitComplete": function (oSettings, json) {
            $(this).closest('#dt_table_tools_wrapper').find('.DTTT.btn-group').addClass('table_tools_group').children('a.btn').each(function () {
                $(this).addClass('btn-sm btn-default');
            });
            $("td:nth-child(1)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("th:nth-child(1)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("td:nth-child(4)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("th:nth-child(4)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("td:nth-child(5)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("th:nth-child(5)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("td:nth-child(6)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("th:nth-child(6)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("td:nth-child(7)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
            $("th:nth-child(7)").addClass('hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs');
        },
        'fnServerData': function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            aoData.push({name: '<?= $this->security->get_csrf_token_name() ?>', value: '<?= $this->security->get_csrf_hash() ?>'});
            aoData.push({name: "sSearch_1", value: iMin});
            aoData.push({name: "sSearch_2", value: iMax});
            $.ajax
                    ({
                        'dataType': 'json',
                        'type': 'POST',
                        'url': sSource,
                        'data': aoData,
                        'success': fnCallback
                    });

        }
    });
```

Comment: dá um order by na sua query no mysql

Comment: @Marconi eu já tentei fazer isso, mas ao colocar o order by algumas funções deixaram de funcionar.